# What Kind of Site Would I Need To DDOS

Tags: php, ddos, denial-of-service, html, iframe

Recently I heard about Distributed Denial of Service and Denial of Service attacks and to see how this worked, I made a quick script (this is not a debug thing, I have an actual question about Cyber Security)

```
function _DDoS(url){
document.body.innerHTML+='<iframe src="'+url+'" style="display:none;"> </iframe>';
}
for(;;){
setTimeout(_DDoS("http://ddosthissiteorsomething.com/index.html"),10);
}
```

Now my question here is would this work against a normal HTML site that displays text and an image or would it need to be against a site that sends post requests to a server or is in php?

I'm really sorry if this is a dumb question I can't find any helpful sites and I thought of Stack but my latest questions haven't been taken in very well.

Comment: This is more likely to just exhaust the client's memory - you're adding iframes to a page (each of which takes memory, even if hidden), containing a single page (which the browser would probably just provide from local cache). In other words, it is likely to cause a single request to the server, then cause your machine to run ever more slowly, until your browser crashes.

Comment: Matthew is correct - you should avoid rendering pages at all. You can simply make http requests without rendering the responses

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, 2 questions. First of all, would turning on something like Cache Killer stop that from happening and secondly, what could I do in JavaScript? And would any of these work:https://github.com/ninja25538/JavaScript-Based-DDOS/blob/master/main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plainly speaking, denial of service attacks can be targetted at anything. The point of a denial of service attack of that nature is simply to overwhelm the target.

Pointing this attack at something that takes longer (such as some sort of more complex php page/request) would yield a more effective denial of service attack, because the server will have to spend more time serving each request. If you're hitting a static page like index.html it's likely that that file could be cached or even served by a proxy - Depending largely on the target server's implementation.

To make the attack more effective, you should consider longer-running queries, such as things that talk to a database or to the filesystem.

<sub>*Minor JavaScript note: You can use setInterval instead of setTimeout in a loop*</sub>